# Why source-highlighter doesn't work in asciidoctor?

Tags: reactjs, asciidoctor

I use asciidoctor in reactjs app and I want use highlight.js for source code selection, but attributes doesn't work.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default, `asciidoctor` produces just the HTML for the Asciidoc source passed to it, not an entire page. If you want the headers and footers for the page, including the code require to fetch and run `highlight.js`, you need to add `standalone: true` to your processing options:

```js
const converted = asciidoc.convert(file, {
  standalone: true,
  attributes: {
    'source-highlighter': 'highlight.js',
    'highlightjs-theme': 'dark',
  }
})
```

See: https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoctor.js/latest/setup/quick-tour/

and: https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoctor.js/latest/processor/convert-options/

Alternatively, you can add the code import highlight.js and ask it to highlight the HTML produced by `asciidoctor`.